# Reference error on function invocation

Tags: javascript, dom, google-maps-api-3

In the below code,

```
<head>
        <title>Geo location</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

            <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript">
                    function showLocation(){
                        if(navigator.geolocation){
                            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
                        }else{
                            alert('geo location is not supported');
                        }
                    }

                    function showPosition(position){
                        console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(position));
                        var mapProp = {
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
                            zoom: 5,
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                          };                
                        new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
                    }
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p> Click below to get your geo location</p>
        <button onclick="showLocation();">Click</button>
        <div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;border: 1px solid red;"></div>
    </body>
```

---

As per debugging, error *`showLocation` is not defined* occurs on click event

`showLocation` is loaded before `onclick` event occurs.

how do I resolve this error?

Comment: Instead of using onclick use addEventListener

Comment: any reason for using `addEventListener`?

Comment: Well if you put all the code in the script then it can't say is not defined.

Comment: @Manu what is the problem in the current code?

Comment: I guess the html is being loaded before the JS. OR The js isn't running at all.

Comment: text in a `<script>` tag that has a `src` attribute is ignored - so, your function is not defined at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript">
                // all this will be ignored as the script tag has a src attribute
                function showLocation(){
                ...
                }

                function showPosition(position){
                ...
                }
        </script>
```

try this instead

```
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
                function showLocation(){
                ...
                }

                function showPosition(position){
                ...
                }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no closing tag of this

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript">
```

it has to be

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Put rest of the js code in a different `script`  tag

[CHECK HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/jx9mpkkq/2/). The error is not there in console.

Answer (score 0):

Add this script tag before the closing body tag and you should be fine. Like this:

```html
<body>
  ...
<script>
                    function showLocation(){
                        if(navigator.geolocation){
                            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
                        }else{
                            alert('geo location is not supported');
                        }
                    }

                    function showPosition(position){
                        console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(position));
                        var mapProp = {
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
                            zoom: 5,
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                          };                
                        new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
                    }
            </script>
<body>
```